# Django : Import static file inside a template doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, static-files

It seems that my static file doesn't work properly in my django project. I'm not sure whether this is exactly related to js files or the whole static file. Checking related questions, I couldn't find how to solve this problem. So, I send what my template should look like and how it looks in my browser in the below screenshots:

what my template should look:(when scrolling down, the background image also moves)

[image: what my template should look:(when scrolling down, the background image called showcase.jpg also moves)]

But this is how my browser shows the template: (no background images, no padding adjustments)

[image: this is how my browser shows the template: (no background images, no padding adjustments)]

This is my base.html codes:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <!-- LightBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.min.css' %}">

    <title>BT Real Estate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Top Bar -->
    {% include 'partials/_topbar.html' %}
    <!-- Navbar -->
    {% include 'partials/_navbar.html' %}
    <!--- Main Content -->

    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    <!-- Footer -->
    {% include 'partials/_footer.html' %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/lightbox.min.js' %} "></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %} "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, this is how I addressed my static file in settings.py:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'listings.apps.ListingsConfig',
    'realtors.apps.RealtorsConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'btre.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'btre.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '******',
        'USER': '******',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'btre/static')
]

# Media Folder Settings
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
```

Here is my urls.py codes:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('listings/', include('listings.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is how I extend base.html in index.html: (I just brought the show case's codes here)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- Showcase -->
    <section id="showcase">
        <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="home-search p-5">
            <div class="overlay p-5">
            <h1 class="display-4 mb-4">
                Property Searching Just Got So Easy
            </h1>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Recusandae quad, 
asperiores eveniet vel nostrum magnam
                voluptatum tempore! Consectetur, id commodi!</p>
            <div class="search">
                <form action="search.html">
                <!-- Form Row 1 -->
                    #pass
{% endblock %}
```

And finally, here is the hierarchy of my static file:

[image: the hierarchy of my static file]

Why did such a problem happen? Can somebody help me out with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: which version of Django do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include in your settings a media root and a media url. I use the following settings.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR),'static']
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

Also then in your URLS, make sure you have the following settings:
(first import static and settings), then enter the following code at the end!

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I think this might fix the problem if the images that aren't displaying are on your local machine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217504/discussion-on-answer-by-muhammad-mashood-django-import-static-file-inside-a-te).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "/cover" and put just "fixed" instead of "fixed/cover" from the "main_app/static/css/style.css/showcase"